# Should a multi disk LVM not use all space?

Tags: lvm

I have two physical volumes in an single volume group.  I extended the home volume to all remaining space with

```
# lvextend -l +100%FREE <home volume>
```

then re-sized the file-system to match

```
# resize2fs  <home volume>
```

Should I have not done that?  I ask because one of the disks occasionally fails and I want to remove it.  However, `pvmove` cannot move the data off that disk because there are no free extents on either drive

```
# pvmove /dev/sdb2
No extents available for allocation
```

which is confirmed with `pvdisplay -m`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have to remove a disk from the LVM, you (obviously) won't be able to access any of the extents on that volume. Thus, if you want to prepare for this eventuality, it can be good to keep each LV on a single PV, and failing this, to keep enough free space in the rest of it to allow you to `pvmove` it off. This is what I do in my own setups. Of course, for real reliability you want multiple layers: consider redundant RAID via either md or LVM's own support, and certainly have regular backups.

In your situation, you probably want to resize the home FS down again (assuming you have enough free space), shrink the LV accordingly, then run `pvmove`. How much you need to shrink it depends on the specific numbers involved, but shouldn't be too difficult to find out.